# How to set text color for ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I defined a ListAdapter:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TimeMode_Choose.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Chooses));
```

Then I defined a background color:

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

But now my problem is that the text color of the whole list is black and I can't see the list.

How can I change the textcolor?

Answer (score 1):

You can do below things to do the desired task

1. create a custom listview or
2. define the style as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="ListFont" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Add this style to your Activity definition in the Manifest XML document as an android:theme attribute, and assign as value the name of the style you created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `getView()` method of `ArrayAdapter`, and change the color of text there.

Create layout(row_layout) like this->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/listItem"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in JAVA Code ->

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TimeMode_Choose.this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listItem, Chooses));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color the layout holding you list to a different color either in xml file or via java code.

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ListView..../>
```

or

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the textcolor?

You don't need to create a custom Adapter(like Vishal suggested), you can also do this using the standard `ArrayAdapter` (assuming you only need one `TextView`).

You just have to use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5b%5d%29) constructor, instead of your current one:

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

Now create a Layout with only a TextView and set it to whatever color you want and set your adapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TimeMode_Choose.this, R.layout.my_layout, R.Id.myTextViewsId, Chooses));
```